# Multiple thread copy IO Operation with Apache IO Java

Tags: java, multithreading, io, copy, apache-commons

I am developing something like a zipping utility which is required in a major project.

What utility does is take the request from the user and start copying all the files asked for to make a zip file and finally provide that zip file to download back to the user.

Now the problem is when the multiple user sends the request then utility initiates a separate thread (can at most be max limit on number of threads defined). Utility starts copying parallely and gets real slow, as good as unusable.

I need a way to solve this or any any method so that parallel copying should be fast enough.

I am Using Apache commons io for copying and Zip4j library for zipping purpose.

Please suggest.

Comment: Did you measure where it gets slow? Some profiling to see where the performance goes away could help to identify the bottle neck. Also some code would be helpful.

Comment: Post some code. Probably you just need to add a `BufferedOutputStream` under the zip stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isFresh) {
    ArrayList<String> foldersNamesToBeZipped =
            GeneralInfoDownload.getFilesToDownloadForWorkstep(this.map.get("DEPARTMENT"));
    ArrayList<File> folderFilesToBeZipped = new ArrayList<File>();

    for (String name : foldersNamesToBeZipped) {
        folderFilesToBeZipped.add(new File(MasterPath + System.getProperty("file.separator") + name));
    }

    log.info("****************Copying start TimeStamp***************" + this.map.get("JID"));
    TDFileUtil.copyFilesToDirectory(folderFilesToBeZipped,
           new File(toPcFolder.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
           + "NEW_ORIGNALS"));
    }
}
```

`GeneralInfoDownload.getFilesToDownloadForWorkstep` function gets all the files which are to zipped and downloaded.

`TDFileUtil.copyFilesToDirectory` function inside uses  Apache commons methods `copyDirectoryToDirectory` and `copyFileToDirectory`.

This works fine when there are only 1 or two requests but its get slow when multiple request gets in line.

This is expected but is there any performance boosting that can be done. (i mean it to be just tolerable.)

Comment: Zipping is fine i can make it parellel with download with SplitStream. but problem is copying the files.